# Iterating over an arbitrary iterable data structure in Go

Tags: arrays, string, function, dictionary, go

I am writing a counter function in Go that accepts an iterable data structure (namely an array, slice, or string), and then counts the elements of that structure:

```
func NewFreqDist(iterable interface{}) *FreqDist {
  fd := FreqDist{make(map[reflect.Value]int)}
  switch reflect.TypeOf(iterable).Kind() {
    case reflect.Array, reflect.Slice, reflect.String:
      i := reflect.ValueOf(iterable)
      for j := 0; j < i.Len(); j++ {
        fd.Samples[i.Index(j)]++
      }
    default:
      Code to handle if the structure is not iterable...
  }
  return &fd
}
```

The `FreqDist` object contains a map (`Samples`) which contains the counts. However, when I print the map outside the function, it looks like this:

```
map[<uint8 Value>:1 <uint8 Value>:1]
```

Accessing a value in the map with a key does not work properly.
The answer suggesting the use of the `reflect` package for this problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025833/range-over-interface-which-stores-a-slice#14026030).
So, how does one go about traversing an arbitrary data structure in Go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top comment on the answer you linked to is

> The only thing to add would be that s.Index(i) returns a reflect.Value so in my case I needed s.Index(i).Interface() to reference the actual value. – Nucleon

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I believe this is your solution. Instead of using `i.Index(j)` to define keys in your map, try `i.Index(j).Interface()`. Your map will need to be `map[interface{}]int`. This way you can use data from the original `iterable` as keys when accessing values in the map.

Here's a playground example I (crudely) adapted from your code: https://play.golang.org/p/Rwtm9EOmyN

Depending on your data, you may want to use [`CanInterface()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.CanInterface) at some point to avoid a panic.