# How to check if interface{} is a slice

Tags: go, interface, type-conversion, slice

I'm noob in Go :) so my question may be stupid, but can't find answer, so.

I need a function:

```
func name (v interface{}) {
    if is_slice() {
        for _, i := range v {
            my_var := i.(MyInterface)
            ... do smth
        }
    } else {
        my_var := v.(MyInterface)
        ... do smth
    }
}
```

How can I do `is_slice` in Go? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Actually my problem is that v is slice of pointers. After some investigate I think it's better iterate over collection in first place, at least implementation I've seen used such approach. Some copy/paste boilerplate code, but I think it won't be a problem for now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [range over interface{} which stores a slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025833/range-over-interface-which-stores-a-slice)

Answer (score 17):

The `is_slice` method can be something like this:

```
func IsSlice(v interface{}) bool {
    return reflect.TypeOf(v).Kind() == reflect.Slice
}
```

Can also put additional condition of `reflect.TypeOf(v).Kind() == reflect.Array` if required.

Comment: This is the actual answer to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to use reflect to convert an interface{} to an array (or slice) of interface{} ?

Comment: // InterfaceSlice converts a slice of any object to a slice of interfaces of those internal objects
// if in is not an addressable item, it will panic
func InterfaceSlice(in any) (o []any) {
 if in == nil {
  return
 }
 v := reflect.ValueOf(in)
 for i := 0; i < v.Len(); i++ {
  o = append(o, v.Index(i).Interface())
 }
 return o
}

Answer (score 15):

In your case the [type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches) is the simplest and most convenient solution:

```
func name(v interface{}) {
    switch x := v.(type) {
    case []MyInterface:
        fmt.Println("[]MyInterface, len:", len(x))
        for _, i := range x {
            fmt.Println(i)
        }
    case MyInterface:
        fmt.Println("MyInterface:", x)
    default:
        fmt.Printf("Unsupported type: %T\n", x)
    }
}
```

The `case` branches enumerate the possible types, and inside them the `x` variable will already be of that type, so you can use it so.

Testing it:

```
type MyInterface interface {
    io.Writer
}

var i MyInterface = os.Stdout
name(i)
var s = []MyInterface{i, i}
name(s)
name("something else")
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ejuMh1ByhV)):

```
MyInterface: &{0x1040e110}
[]MyInterface, len: 2
&{0x1040e110}
&{0x1040e110}
Unsupported type: string
```

For a single type check you may also use [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions):

```
if x, ok := v.([]MyInterface); ok {
    // x is of type []MyInterface
    for _, i := range x {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
} else {
    // x is not of type []MyInterface or it is nil
}
```

There are also other ways, using package [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) you can write a more general (and slower) solution, but if you're just starting Go, you shouldn't dig into reflection yet.

Answer (score 3):

[icza's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40343605/20601) is correct, but is not recommended by [go creators](https://youtu.be/PAAkCSZUG1c?t=7m35s):

> interface{} says nothing

A better approach may be to define a function for each type you have:

```
func name(v MyInterface) {
    // do something
}

func names(vs []MyInterface) {
    for _, v := range(vs) {
        name(v)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wondering why creators of fmt package didn't create print function for every   type?

Comment: Thanks for interesting link.

Comment: @Alexander you have a somewhat "print for every type" implemented as the Print verbs: %s for strings,%p for pointers, %d for integers of base 10, etc, and you can use %s and implement your own String() string function to print your own type

Comment: Please mind that in this case you won't be able to directly pass into your function a slice of values, because slice of interfaces is not an interface: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InterfaceSlice

Answer (score 0):

From https://blog.golang.org/json

Decoding arbitrary data

Consider this JSON data, stored in the variable b:

```
b := []byte(`{"Name":"Wednesday","Age":6,"Parents":["Gomez","Morticia"]}`)
```

Without knowing this data's structure, we can decode it into an interface{} value with Unmarshal:

var f interface{}
err := json.Unmarshal(b, &f)
At this point the Go value in f would be a map whose keys are strings and whose values are themselves stored as empty interface values:

```
f = map[string]interface{}{
    "Name": "Wednesday",
    "Age":  6,
    "Parents": []interface{}{
        "Gomez",
        "Morticia",
    },
}
```

To access this data we can use a type assertion to access f's underlying map[string]interface{}:

```
m := f.(map[string]interface{})
```

We can then iterate through the map with a range statement and use a type switch to access its values as their concrete types:

```
for k, v := range m {
    switch vv := v.(type) {
    case string:
        fmt.Println(k, "is string", vv)
    case float64:
        fmt.Println(k, "is float64", vv)
    case []interface{}:
        fmt.Println(k, "is an array:")
        for i, u := range vv {
            fmt.Println(i, u)
        }
    default:
        fmt.Println(k, "is of a type I don't know how to handle")
    }
}
```

In this way you can work with unknown JSON data while still enjoying the benefits of type safety.