# How to check variable declared as map[string]interface{} is actually map[string]string?

Tags: go

I have a variable that needs to be either a `string` or `map[string]string` (will be deserializing from JSON). So I declare it as `interface{}`. How can I check that the value is `map[string]string`?

This question [How to check interface is a map[string]string in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384879/how-to-check-interface-is-a-mapstringstring-in-golang) almost answers my question. But the accepted answer only works if the variable is declared as a `map[string]string` not if the variable is `interface{}`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    var myMap interface{}
    myMap = map[string]interface{}{
        "foo": "bar",
    }
    _, ok := myMap.(map[string]string)
    if !ok {
        fmt.Println("This will be printed")
    }
}
```

See https://play.golang.org/p/mA-CVk7bdb9

I can use two type assertions though. One on the map and one on the map value.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var myMap interface{}
    myMap = map[string]interface{}{
        "foo": "bar",
    }

    valueMap, ok := myMap.(map[string]interface{})
    if !ok {
        fmt.Println("will not be printed")
    }
    for _, v := range valueMap {
        if _, ok := v.(string); !ok {
            fmt.Println("will not be printed")
        }
    }
}
```

See https://play.golang.org/p/hCl8eBcKSqE

Question: is there a better way?

Comment: Let me know how to improve my question if you downvoted it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you declare a variable as type `interface{}`, it *is* type `interface{}`.  It *is not*, ever, some `map[keytype]valuetype` value.  But a variable of type `interface{}` can *hold* a value that has some other concrete type.  When it does so, it does so—that's all there is to it.  It still *is* type `interface{}`, but it *holds* a value of some other type.

#### An interface value has two parts

The key distinction here is between what an `interface{}` variable *is*, and what it *holds*.  Any interface variable actually has two slots inside it: one to hold what *type* is stored in it, and one to hold what *value* is stored in it.  Any time you—or anyone—assign a value *to* the variable, the compiler fills in both slots: the type, from the type of the value you used, and the value, from the value you used.<sup>1</sup>  The interface variable compares equal to nil if it has `nil` in *both* slots; and that's also the default zero value.

Hence, your runtime test:

```
valueMap, ok := myMap.(map[string]interface{})
```

is a sensible thing to do: if `myMap` holds a value that has type `map[string]interface`, `ok` gets set to `true` and `valueMap` contains the value (which has that type).  If `myMap` holds a value with some other type, `ok` gets set to `false` and `valueMap` gets set to the zero-value of type `map[string]interface{}`.  In other words, at runtime, the code checks the type-slot first, then either copies the value-slot across to `valueMap` and sets `ok` to true, or sets `valueMap` to `nil` and sets `ok` to false.

If and when `ok` has been set to `true`, each `valueMap[k]` value *is* type `interface{}`.   As before, for `myMap` itself, each of these `interface{}` variables can—but do not have to—hold a value of type `string`, and you *must* use some sort of "what is the actual type-and-value" run-time test to tease them apart.

When you use [`json.Unmarshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) to stuff decoded JSON into a variable of type `interface{}`, it is capable of deserializing any of these documented JSON types.  The list then tells you what *type* gets stuffed into the interface variable:

> ```
> bool, for JSON booleans
> float64, for JSON numbers
> string, for JSON strings
> []interface{}, for JSON arrays
> map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects
> nil for JSON null
> ```

So after doing `json.Unmarshal` into a variable of type `interface{}`, you *should* check what type got put into the type-slot of the variable.  You can do this with an assertion and an `ok` boolean, or you can, if you prefer, use a [*type switch*](https://tour.golang.org/methods/16) to decode it:

```
var i interface
if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &i); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
switch v := i.(type) {
case string:
    ... code ...
case map[string]interface{}:
    ... code ...
... add some or all of the types listed ...
}
```

The thing is, no matter what you do in code here, you *did* have `json.Unmarshal` put something into an `interface{}`, and `interface{}` *is* the type of `i`.  You must test at runtime what *type and value pair* the interface holds.

Your other option is to inspect your JSON strings manually and decide what type of variable to provide to `json.Unmarshal`.  That gives you less code to write *after* the `Unmarshal`, but more code to write *before* it.

There's a more complete example [here, on the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IKD4kM1Q6u-), of using type switches to inspect the result from a `json.Unmarshal`.  It's deliberately incomplete but, I think, has enough input and output cases to let you work out how to handle everything, given the quote above about what `json.Unmarshal` writes into a variable of type `interface{}`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Of course, if you assign one `interface{}` from some other `interface{}`:

```
var i1, i2 interface{}
... set i1 from some actual value ...
// more code, then:
i2 = i1
```

the compiler just copies both slots from `i1` into `i2`.  The two-separate-slots thing becomes clearer when you do:

```
var f float64
... code that sets f to, say, 1.5 ...
i2 = f
```

for instance, as that writes `float64` into the type-slot, and the value `1.5` into the value-slot.  The compiler *knows* that `f` is `float64` so the type-setting just means "stick a constant in it".  The compiler doesn't necessarily know the *value* of `f` so the value-setting is a copy of whatever the actual value is.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So is my second code snippet of using two type assertions a good approach? Also curious of other ways other than type switches to do this, if any.

Comment: Well, define "good". :-) If you use `json.Unmarshal` into an `interface{}` you *must* test the result somehow in order to use it, and there are only a few variants of the somehow: type switch, type assertion with `ok` variable, or type assertion without `ok` variable (which will panic at runtime if the type is not what you claim it must be). The *only* way to avoid this is to call `json.Unmarshal` with a pointer to a variable of some type other than `interface{}`. That in turn means "inspect the json to see what to expect". Pick one of these two methods.